Read CSV with "§" as delimiter using Databricks autoloader
I'm very new to spark streaming and autoloader and had a query on how we might be able to get autoloader to read a text file with "§" as the delimiter. Below I tried reading the file as a CSV.
Tried running below:
val df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
  .option("delimeter", "§")
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("path-to-the-csv-file")

but it did not work and got this output:
Image1
Figured it might be an encoding related issue, so tried running the below:
val df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
  .option("delimeter", "§")
  .option("encoding", "Cp1252") //ANSI  
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("path-to-the-csv-file")

This time I'm able to see the "§" in the output, but the delimiter still doesn't work as shown here
Please help!
Edit - I have tried replacing "§" with the Unicode equivalent "U+00A7" and it still doesn't work.

It might be related that your § might be UTF-8 or another encoding before your call is sending it to the spark reader. Can you try to copy paste one of those § as delimeter, to see if it makes a difference?

@Arcturus - tried doing just that, no luck :(

Most modern text editors use utf-8 (some use utf-16) by default. But your data files are encoded using CP-1252. So... that you are seeing that § in your code .option("delimeter", "§") is utf-8 §. But your files have no utf-8 §, so it will not split the lines. Even copy pasting will not work.

So, it looks like the order of the .option() that we pass into the autoloader matters!
For example, the below works:
val df2 = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
  .option("encoding", "Cp1252") // ANSI
  .option("delimiter", "§") // §
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(schema)
  .load(file_path)

The below does not:
val df3 = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
  .option("delimeter", "§")
  .option("encoding", "Cp1252") //ANSI  
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(schema)
  .load(file_path)

The encoding has to be set before we set the delimiter for this to work.

Damn! good find! Well done!

As your data files are in CP-1252, you will need to provide your delimiter in the same encoding.
Luckily the CP-1252 <> UTF-8 conversions are loss less from what I know. So... you can create an utf-8 string... convert it to bytes
.option(
  "delimeter",
  new String("\u00A7".getBytes("Windows-1252"), "Windows-1252")
)


thanks for the response. I tried this out but I'm still running into the same issue :(

What is this cloudFiles format ?

cloudFiles is for using Autoloader

The above works for me but that might be because I am using different input data. Can you share the sample data file somewhere ? Also... I now realise that my current answer is kind of non-sense... even the simple .option("delimeter", "§") is working with my sample data.
